# WPF Multipage app

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm coding my application which has one window `MainWindow`. There is two pages `Page1` and `Page2`. `Page1` has one textbox and button `Next`. `Page2` has two textboxes and buttons `Back` and `Next`. How can i make transition to `Page2` from `Page1` by clicking button `Next`, transmitting text from textbox on `Page1` to textboxes on `Page2`, and get back to `Page1`, saving text in textbox on `Page1`?

In which container should i pull this pages(Window, Frame, NavigatedWindow)?

Comment: Start reading here: [Navigation Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/navigation-overview).

Comment: What i used to do is creating a `TabControl` with TabPages for all of my visible screens. Then you can switch between them by just setting the `TabControl.SelectedIndex` to your desire. You can hide the TabPage-Header by setting their `Visibility` property to `Collapsed`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Page Navigation

```
Page2 p2 = new Page2("This is Page2"); 
this.NavigationService.Navigate(p2);
```

Link : [wpf-page-navigation](http://miteshsureja.blogspot.in/2012/03/wpf-page-navigation.html)

**Note : This is not a good practice to just ask question , first you have to try and if you get any error ask for solution.**